# Java generics- constructor type

Tags: java, generics

```
public class AClass<X extends AnInterface>{

    public AClass(X x){
    }

}

public class Y implements AnInterface{

}
```

In the calling code if I have:

```
public static<X extends AnInterface> void main(String args){

    AnInterface y = new Y();
    AClass a = new AClass<AnInterface>(y);

}
```

I should be able to get this to work using X in the constructor for AClass right? I am getting errors telling me the contructor for AClass should be of type AnInterface??

EDITED to change `AClass a = new AClass<AnInterface>(y);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell AClass what type its expecting.

```
    public static void main(String args){
        AnInterface y = new Y();
        AClass<AnInterface> a = new AClass<AnInterface>(y);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I do have that- I had to re-type my code out here and missed that bit. Its complaining about the type of the constructor for AClass.

Comment: Look at my code and see if you can spot the difference :) You need to declare a as AClass<AnInterface> too. Thing is, I suspect there is a better solution to your problem although can't tell from this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnInterface y = new Y();
    AClass a = new AClass(y);
}
```

Comment: That doesnt get rid of the warning.